# Calling Console app from SharePoint Workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-word, workflow

I need to open a Word document from a SharePoint workflow, and print it to a specific printer tray.  I first attempted to create a Word app instance using the Word.Interop, however my doc object always returned null.   I have read that this is not a supported use of the WordInterop.  So now I am looking for alternatives

I wrote a simple Console app that accepts the word document, Printer name, and tray number as parameters.  The console app works great at the command prompt, but I am having trouble calling it form a SharePoint workflow CodeActivity

```
string urlWord = GetwordDocument(printType);

System.Diagnostics.Process prcs = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
prcs.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\DocxPrint2Tray.exe";
prcs.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(" \"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\" ",urlWord,  printerName, printerTray);
prcs.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
prcs.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
prcs.Start();

string prcsOut = prcs.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
prcs.WaitForExit();
```

The Code appears to hang at the *prcs.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()* line.  Does SharePoint workflows support calling an external process?  Open to any code suggestions and alternative solutions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I cheated....  I finally just copied the files to a folder, and wrote a Windows Service to monitor folder and print the files.  Not my preferred solution, but then push comes to shove you just have to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is PowerShell.  SharePoint unfortunately does not integrate PS to workflows however there are third-party tools that do.  (We created a homegrown one to avoid licensing.)  Once you have PS at your disposal there is little that you cannot do from a workflow including calling a console app.

Here's how we integrated PS.  Create a tasks list called System Tasks.  When a workflow initiates write an entry to this list; that entry is effectively an event.  The entry should carry enough information to be useful to PS.  Have a scheduled PS job running on some interval and reading/processing the System Tasks list.  It should treat entries as messages to be processed.  Different entries will carry different data:

```
EVENT-X Y Z
```

The lead node `EVENT-X` is your event message.  `Y` and `Z` your arguments, parameters, whatever.  Obviously, you can relay as much information as you want.  The scheduled PS job will dispatch different events to different PS scripts for processing and then check off the system task once completed.